# MVC4 Razor @helper not supported / alternatives?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I really want to start using @Helpers in a project but I hear they are not supported in MVC4?

Are they any alternatives that could be easily used to create custom components in an MVC3/4 razor view?

Comment: Where did you see that `@helper` is not support in MVC4?